# Merge lines into a huge single line without "spaces" using sed in .txt file

Tags: bash, sed, merge

Can't find any solution for this case using sed:

I have .txt files which contain more than 30~ lines in average.
I need to merge all the lines into a single huge one without any "spaces" for every file(N amount of files but less than 1000) and paste this line into a new one (1 line for each txt file data). Need this format to parse to .csv table.

Example:

file 1:

```
    This file 
Contains text 
to merge into
a single line without any
 space between characters
```

file 2:

```
    This file 
Contains almost the same text 
to merge into
a single line without any
 space or blanks between characters after the merge
```

file N:

```
    This file 
Contains equal text 
to merge into
a single line without any
 space between characters
```

Output:

```
This FileContains Textto Merge intoa single line without anyspace between characters
This fileContains almost the same texto merge intoa single line without anyspace or blanks between characters after the merge
This fileContains equal textto merge intoa single line without anyspace between characters
```

Tried with:

```
sed -e :a -e '/$/N; s/\n//; ta' test.txt
```

Didn't work. Text remains the same

Sample Data:

```
6150217008*AA*31/1*1 
0*4611*1 
349*9171*349*9171*0*0
403*9481*403*9481*0*0
C3*25*
718*17399*718*17399*0*0
C4*25*
794*19293*794*19293*0*0
C5*25*
731*17594*731*17594*0*0
C6*25*
```

Need to get: 
6150217008*AA*31/1*10*4611*1349*9171*349*9171*0*0403*9481*403*9481*0*0C3*2....etc

A huge single raw line text without any spaces.

How can I make that? Thanks!

Comment: `sed ':1;s/^[ ]*//;s/[ ]*$//;$!{N;s/\n//;b1}'`

Comment: 6150217008*VA*V1/1*1
DIX*DN 5800-4*7008**EVS3.1*
0*4611*1
865616*37165*865616*37165*0*0
etc...
Almost delete all lines, but not all of them

Comment: Maybe you should edit your Sample Data because it doesn’t show any whitespace and I guess it should contain some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple ***tr*** command approach:

```
tr -d '[:space:]' < test.txt
```

The output:

```
6150217008*AA*31/1*10*4611*1349*9171*349*9171*0*0403*9481*403*9481*0*0C3*25*718*17399*718*17399*0*0C4*25*794*19293*794*19293*0*0C5*25*731*17594*731*17594*0*0C6*25*
```

---

`-d` - to delete characters

`[:space:]` - set of characters representing all horizontal and vertical whitespace

https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr

---

To redirect the output to a new file use the following:

```
tr -d '[:space:]' < test.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This will delete all whitespaces. I think the OP wants to get rid of the first and last whitespaces only.

Comment: Works on output of terminal. How can I save the output with the same format in .txt/csv file? Thanks a million!

Comment: @vdavid, *A huge single raw line text without **any** spaces.*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Can I maintain this command to a folder instead of a single file? Saving the result into the same file where it was read out  (result takes from "input" goes to "tempFile" and saves into the same "input") for each file inside the folder (File shouldn't be specified in command, but result should be saved in the same file where it was read out)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/^\s+|\s*$//g' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash solution which'll spare the whitespace within the strings but trims leading and tailing whitespace:

```
#! /bin/bash

for fname in *.txt; do
    while read -r line || [[ -n ${line} ]]; do
        printf "%s" "${line}"
    done < "${fname}"
    printf "\n"
# don't name the result file .txt if it's in the same dir or it'll be included
done > result.dat
```

This script is assumed to be run in the dir where the txt-files are. You can tweak that part by editing the `for`-loop